# Sitecore Redirect Not Working for Item of Type "Redirect Pattern"

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301, http-redirect, sitecore8.2

I'm a developer working on creating some redirects on www.willistowerswatson.com.  I am using the *https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/3/301_Redirect_module.aspx?sc_lang=en* tool, which uses very similar redirect concepts to what already exists in sitecore.  I have created a **/sitecore/system/Modules/Redirect Module/Redirects/SampleRegExRedirect** item, which uses the /sitecore/templates/Redirect Module/**Redirect Pattern** template.  Here's what I have set its fields to:

**Requested Expression**:   ^https://www.willistowerswatson.com/somepath/(.+)$

**Response Status Code**: 301 Moved Permanently

**Source Item**: /sitecore/content/WTW-Home/$1

The goal is to redirect a links like **https://www.willistowerswatson.com/somepath/industries** to the valid link **https://www.willistowerswatson.com/en/industries** .  However, it's not working at all.  I get a "Page not Found" when I try to hit https://www.willistowerswatson.com/en/somepath/industries or https://tw-local.willistowerswatson.com/somepath/industries (without culture code).  I even tried setting the "Requested Expression" field to :   ^https://www.willistowerswatson.com/en/somepath/(.+)$ and that didn't work either.

What I am doing wrong?  I know this tool is a sitecore feature, but the regular expressions used should have the same syntax.  Can anyone please help?  Thanks!

Comment: Just a (not-verified) thought, but does the origin need to be a full url? Did you try with "^/somepath/(.+)$" ?

Comment: And did you publish?

Comment: @Gatogordo I did both, nothing worked.